# Java try-catch vs instanceof

Tags: java

I have written an error handle as like below.

Type#1

```
try{
  // Logic
} catch (SpecificException e){
  // Handle error-1
} catch (Exception e){
  if(e.getCause() instanceof SpecificException){
     // Handle error-1
  }
  // Handle error-2
}
```

But, for a better clarity and performance I thought of improving the code as like below

Type#2

```
try{
  // Logic
} catch (Exception e){
  if(e instanceof SpecificException || e.getCause() instanceof SpecificException){
     // Handle error-1
  }
  // Handle error-2
}
```

Which type would be better based on JVM aspects?

P.S. In this example, I need to handle generic exception type along with specific exception type, hence question of handling came up.

Comment: It's pretty irrelevant. Especially performance-wise.

Comment: can you not have multiple catch statements in Java? order them from most specific to least specific. Do this meet your needs?

Comment: @Jimmy notice the usage of `Exception.getCause()`

Comment: You need to add `else `block inside your `catch(Exception e)` to handle 'Handle error-2', am I right?

Comment: One should neither catch nor throw `Exception`.

Comment: Please avoid multi-catch answers. The question is unrelated to that. It is purely about handling Exception versus instanceof check where the intention is to get good knowledge on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From performance point of view, there won't be a difference.

In Java, the `catch` blocks' order matters, and you can catch a subclass of the stated exception. This means that JVM cannot really use any maps or indexes and has to do a lookup in exception table, the logic thus being similar to a series of `if (e instanceof XXX)`'s - which is basically your second way.

The readability aspect is opinion-based, so I won't comment on that.

[JavaWorld has an article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076868/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-exceptions.html) that explains what is happening during catch on bytecode / JVM level.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks @Jiri

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second options are NOT the same because `//Handle error-2` logic will be called even for `instanceof SpecificException` or you might need to add an else block to handle this, like shown below:

```
try{
  // Logic
} catch (Exception e){
  if(e instanceof SpecificException || e.getCause() instanceof SpecificException){
     // Handle error-1
  } else {//else block for other exceptions?
    // Handle error-2
  }
}
```

As you mentioned, anyhow if you have to handle `Exception` (but, in general, it is NOT good practice to handle generic `Exception` type), your second option is more better and readable than calling for  `// Handle error-1` and `//Handle error-2` at multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of avoiding to repeat the `Handle error-1` code block (even if it would be just one line), I would probably go with option #2.

If you use this pattern frequently, I would also probably consider trying to wrap it in an utility method, similar e.g. to those given in Guava's [`Throwables`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html) class (I'm not sure if it already contains something which could address your case).